# How to debug Google Analytics Tracking error (_gaq.push returns '3')

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

SUMMARIZE:

I misunderstood the usage of content script. And that leads to this issue. Here is a quote from Google's official doc:

> Execution environment
>
> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated
>   world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into,
>   but **not** to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page.
>   It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript
>   executing on the page it is running on. **The same is true in reverse**:
>   JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any
>   variables defined by content scripts.

More details:
[Content Script tracking with Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372107/content-script-tracking-with-google-analytics/12985606)

--

I am adding some tracking code into a Chrome Extension. But when I test it, the _gaq.push returns number 3. As I tested, I figured that if I call _gaq.push in the extension, the number will keep rising. But when I call it in the console, it's all fine (all the same code).

I am wondering how I can do to track deeper into this error?

Thanks very much for every answer!

UPDATE:

When I trace the return value of _gaq, it is still an array. That means ga.js is not loaded, right?

But it seems ga.js is never loaded in my script. Unless I manually type _gaq in the console, it's an object. This is very weird.

I checked the DOM and found that  tag is already added.

I reviewed the Network panel, find that ga.js is not loaded at all in the queue. But why I can still use console to access the _gaq object?

UPDATE2:

I use console.log to track the value of "window._gaq" and found that the return value of console.log(window._gaq) is DIFFERENT than directly type "window._gaq" in the console. It's totally two different objects. I even use a setInterval function to log the results and it's keeping returning the array, not the expected object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When ran through your script `_gaq` is jut a regular Array. And just like any Array in JavaScript it has the method `push` that inserts one or more elements into the Array and returns the final length of the array.

eg:

```
var _gaq = [];
> undefined
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
> 1
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mysite.com']);
> 2
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'], 
          ['_trackEvent', 'cat', 'act']);
> 4
```

After the ga.js file is loaded the `_gaq` Array is read so the instructions pushed into it can be processed and then the `_gaq` Array is replaced with an object. The object implements the push function as well. But notice that in this case the push function will execute an instruction into the ga.js library and then return 0.

eg:

```
var _gaq = {
  push: function(){
    // Do something here
    return 0;
  }
};
> undefined
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'])
> 0
```

That's a very smart Google design to create an API that can be used even before the library (ga.js) has been loaded.

That's why during your script `_gaq.push` is a method of the Array class and return increasing numbers and on the console it always returns 0.

This is not a problem at all. It seems to be working as intended.

**UPDATE**

It seems that ga.js is already loaded. Maybe it was cached and not showing on the network panel.

ga.js is loaded by this part of the tracking script:

```
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

It is loaded asynchronously. So after this snippet is executed it will be loaded but the exact point where it is loaded is unknown.

If you need to know when the ga.js file is loaded, you can push a callback into _gaq and it will be executed when the ga.js file is loaded.

eg:

```
_gaq.push(function(){
  console.log('ga.js loaded!');
  debugger;
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. I add a new tracking code and found that when I trace the return value of _gaq, it is still an Array. That means ga.js is still not loaded. But the question is, it's never loaded in my script, unless I use console.log to trace the _gaq. It's very weird. I have updated my question.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo I updated my answer, but you better explain better what are you trying to debug. Just check for the gif requests, if they are  being sent then it's working.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I checked and the quest is not sent. I finally figure out that this might be a issue with the valid scope of the Chrome Extension script. The objects I defined from the content script in the extension cannot be reached from the console panel directly. Maybe it's not a GA issue but a Chrome issue. Do you have any good suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't inject Google Analytics tracking code into the content scripts. You're running code that could be affected by code on the page. You better send a message from the contant script to a background script to perform a tracking and then you track from the background page.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo! I will look into that. Your answers helped me a LOT! :)

Comment: Still got some trouble :( Would you please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985723/google-analytics-tracking-in-chrome-extensions-background-html