# Google Analytics tracking in Chrome Extension's background.html

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

When I realized that I cannot track directly in content script. I start to work with background HTML tracking my data. via [Content Script tracking with Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372107/content-script-tracking-with-google-analytics/12985606#12985606)

When I set up my background script, I figured out that it doesn't support inline script. So I put the code in a js file and use "src=filename.js" to include that. via [chrome extension insert content script on browser action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545743/chrome-extension-insert-content-script-on-browser-action)

But finally there is a trouble: I cannot load ga.js at all because it still violates the rule. Here is what I got:

> Refused to load the script 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

My extension structure:

1. background.html
2. script.js
3. tracker.js

---

More information about this issue:

**background.html:**

```
<html>
<script src="tracker.js"></script>
<body></body>
</html>
```

**tracker.js:** *(I hide my ID)*

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', _gaID]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script');
  ga.type = 'text/javascript';
  ga.async = true;
  ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks good. You are on the right track. You just need to update your manifest.json file to allow scripts to be downloaded from the google domain.

Assuming you are using manifest.json file with `manifest_version:2`. You should add this line to the manifest

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
```

More info:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/tut_analytics/

Comment: Oh, thanks! It's working completely now and I have submitted my extension :)

Comment: Anyone knows can I view tracking in debug mode? Or this just affect when submit to store. I do as above tutorial, but in GA nothing to see when I use debug mode.