# Google Analytics tracking isn't working in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, tracking

I tried this method:

> [Google Analytics tracking in Chrome Extension's background.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985723/google-analytics-tracking-in-chrome-extensions-background-html)

as well as official tracking method for extension but it's not working. i'm a newbie and i tried only 2 methods till now that i mentioned above but it's not working i can't track, nothing showing in analytics, is there any thing i'm wrong doing?

Comment: To use Google Analytics with Chrome Extension, I would suggest that you go over the [Tutorial: Google Analytics](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics) guide. It demonstrates using Google Analytics to track the usage of your extension. However, it expects that you're familiar with Chrome Extensions developement.

Comment: @noogui Ofc i'm familiar with Chrome Extensions developement but still in newbie phase and i tried it that's why i said **as well as official tracking method** but it's not working

Comment: This answer works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24165203/2724961