# Trying to add Google Analytics to Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I have looked through several [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560583/add-google-analytics-to-a-chrome-extension) about adding GA to my chrome extension but have had no luck yet.

So far this is my analytics code

`analytics.js`

```js
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

And of course, I have already added my GA ID.The main error I keep getting is

```
analytics.js:3 Refused to load the script 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

In reference to the [tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics), I have added the following to my manifest.json
`manifest.json`

```json
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
```

However, even after adding this to my extension, I keep getting the error in my dev console.

For reference, here is the script in my `index.html`

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Polus</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type='image/png' href="images/polus_tab_icon.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/calendar-style.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/analytics.js"></script>

  </head>
```

Please help if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your content policy declaration in manifest.json doesn't work since it refers to the different domain than `www.google-analytics.com`. Also, to use Universal Analytics script `analytics.js` you'd also need to adjust settings to disable protocol check. Take a look at this tutorial https://davidsimpson.me/2014/05/27/add-googles-universal-analytics-tracking-chrome-extension/

Comment: Thank you for your help! In addition to this, I realized that after changing the manifest I needed to reload my extension.

Answer (score 1):

By the way Google Analytics 4 (gta.js) has not implemented the checkProtocolTask. So for the time being tacking Google Extensions with GA4 is not going to work. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174954288?pli=1 for the latest status