# NOT A DUPLICATE - Adding GA4 (not UA) Measurement Protocol to Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, service-worker, google-analytics-4, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Has anyone successfully added GA4 analytics to a Chrome Extension using the Measurement Protocol (gtag).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497548/chrome-extension-make-it-run-every-page-load) has the details for Universal Analytics, but has not been updated for GA4 which has a different protocol.

I have copied the exact code from the [google instructions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag) into the service worker (also validated by the [Event Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/event-builder/)):

```
const measurement_id = `G-XXXXXXXXXX`;
const api_secret = `<secret_value>`;

fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurement_id}&api_secret=${api_secret}`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYYY',
    events: [{
      name: 'tutorial_begin',
      params: {},
    }]
  })
});
```

The extension console serves no errors, I just don't see any event data coming through to GA.

**UPDATE**

I managed to get it to work by moving the const values into the fetch url:

```
fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=G-XXXXXXXXXX&api_secret=secret_value`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYYY',
    events: [{
      name: 'tutorial_begin',
      params: {},
    }]
  })
});
```

Comment: Add the API site to `host_permissions` and make the request in any extension script except content script. See also [Add google analytics into a chrome extension using manifest v3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73825802)

Comment: @wOxxOm I have already added this - it still doesn't work. That post is for UA and doesn't reflect the changes needed for GA4. I mentioned that in the post.

Comment: The answer I've linked is for GA4 Measurement Protocol. What do you see in [devtools -> Network inspector](/a/10258029) for the request? Also, AFAIK, you can't have URL parameters when using POST so maybe that example is incorrect despite being official.

Comment: @wOxxOm the taxonomy used in that answer is the UA taxonomy. GA4 has a different structure. I don't know exactly what to look for in the network console but the fetch request is showing a status of 204 and no errors? Maybe the query parameters are where its breaking?