# Can't understand how I should structure my chrome extension with manfiest V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api

I am trying to build a plugin that transcribes what I say into Google Docs.  In many examples that I found, they use manfiest V2 and there is a `background.html` that has a scripts like `<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>` and then running the google API. My problem is that I got confused about managing my `manifest.josn` and `foreground.js` files and how should I call for gapi. Here are my files:

**manifest.js**

```
{
"name": "Docs Live Transcriber Plugin",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "A plugin for voice dictation and voice functions for GDocs.",
"manifest_version": 3,
"author": "",
"icons": {
    "128": "img/logo.png"
},
"permissions": [
    "https://docs.google.com/document/",
    "https://script.google.com/",
    "identity",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "management",
    "notifications",
    "unlimitedStorage"
],
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "",
    "api_key": "",
    "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "profile"],
    "discovery_docs": ["https://docs.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://docs.google.com/*"],
        "js": ["foreground.js"]
    }
],
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' ; object-src 'self'"
},
"host_permissions": ["https://www.googleapis.com/*"]
```

}

**foreground.js**

```
const createButton = (buttonId, eventListiner, innerText) => {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('id', button_type);
    button.setAttribute('onclick', eventListiner);
    button.innerText = innerText;
    return button;
};

const createScript = (link, load) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = link;
    script.setAttribute('defer', '');
    script.setAttribute('async', '');
    script.setAttribute('onload', load);
    return script;
};

////////////////////// GAPI / GIS Initialization //////////////////////
const waitGAPI = createScript(
    'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js',
    'gapiLoaded()'
);
const waitGIS = createScript(
    'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js',
    'gapiLoaded()'
);

function gapiLoaded() {
    gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
}

async function initializeGapiClient() {
    await gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
    });
    gapiInited = true;
    maybeEnableButtons();
}

function gisLoaded() {
    tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        callback: '', // defined later
    });
    gisInited = true;
    maybeEnableButtons();
}

const signIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, (token) => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError || !token) {
            alert(
                `SSO ended with an error: ${JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError)}`
            );
            return;
        }
        signInWithCredential(auth, GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, token))
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('signed in!');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                alert(`SSO ended with an error: ${err}`);
            });
    });
};
```

Comment: Try the new GA4, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73825802).

Comment: Well, I need it for google docs. + everytime I've tried to access GA4, it is down.